# Drupal 8 already installed, and sometimes it doesn't. Can PHP fix this?

Tags: php, debugging, drupal

I downloaded Drupal 8 connecting to IIS, and mysql (mssql as well). When I proceed to install Drupal 8, it tells me that it is already installed. When I delete `settings.php`, it sometimes would actually install all the way. Sometimes it just says batch error. Other times Drupal says "already installed".

I notice when the site loads, it takes a long time saying "waiting for localhost".

I have php storm running proficiently but it did not find the errors. So maybe it wasn't the file itself.Is there a specific way php storm can fix this?

If anyone can please help me, feel free, I really need guidance for this.

Below are images to what is on my screen.

[Link to how I set up the entire file/process. I am aware its mssql. I used both](http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-8-windows)

[image: Sometimes it says already installed]

Other times, it displays a no active batch error.

This only occurs with Drupal 8. WordPress, Joomla, and Drupal 7 works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's normally occurs when you really have the Drupal installed on your database.

Try to delete the database that is configured on your `settings.php` and run the `/install.php` again.

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, however I have tried that recently. Drupal eithers states that Drupal is installed again, says a batch error, or it installs. The results happen with a new database, and default settings as well. When I see, "Drupal already installed", I look at the database, seeing only 23 tables installed. It just stops installing tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by copying code of **default.settings.php** into your **settings.php** and install it into empty database.